# How to z-normalize multi-dimensional time series?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, computational-statistics

z-normalization for 1-dim time series is simple.

$z_i = (x_i-m)/s$

Here, $x_i$ is the element of series for each time index $i$.

$m$ is the mean, and $s$ is the standard deviation.

For n-dim time series, I can estimate $m$ easily, but I don't know how to estimate $s$.

Do I need to estimate covariance matrix and multiply its inverse?

Also, the number of elements of time series is smaller than the dimension of each element.

Comment: In the usual version, $s$ is the standard deviation, not the variance.

Comment: I'd expect each time series to be scaled separately. Why do otherwise?

Comment: It is a strange problem then if your time series is shorter than the dimension of the covariance matrix. You may have to regularize it somehow (make invertible, usually be adding a small positive definite matrix). Either you have a short time series, in which case your results are suspect because you may fail to reach the sample sizes sufficient for the traditional asymptotics; or your dimension is so large that you need to use "large $p$, small $n$" asymptotics instead (which is entirely different and absolutely weird).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to multiply by the inverse square root:
$$
X\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma) \Rightarrow Z = \Sigma^{-1/2}(X-\mu) \sim N_p(0_p,I_p)
$$
Now, the concept of a square root of the matrix is not uniquely defined. For a symmetric positive definite matrix, as covariance matrices are, there are two decent choices:

1. [Spectral decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) (aka principal component analysis) square root:
   $$
   \Sigma = U \Lambda U', \mbox{ where } \Lambda={\rm diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_p), \lambda_1 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_p > 0; U'U = UU' = I_p
   $$
   $$
   \Rightarrow \Omega_s = U\Lambda^{-1/2}U', \Lambda^{-1/2} = {\rm diag}(\lambda_1^{-1/2}, \ldots, \lambda_p^{-1/2})
   $$
   is such square root:
   $$
   \Omega_s \Sigma \Omega_s = U\Lambda^{-1/2}U' U\Lambda U' U\Lambda^{-1/2}U' = U\Lambda^{-1/2} \Lambda \Lambda^{-1/2} U' = U U' = I_p
   $$
2. [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) is another popular square root:
   $$
   \exists \mbox{ lower triangular } L: \Sigma = LL'
   $$

My feeling is that Cholesky might be a bit more stable numerically. There are probably other options for square roots, but these appear to be the more popular ones that can be easily found in most computing environments.

Comment: Thanks! However, Unfortunately, the number of elements of time series is smaller than the dimension of each element. Therefore, covariance matrix is not positive definite, and Cholesky will be failed. Is it ok to use spectral decomposition in this case?

Comment: You can, and you will probably end up with the square root of Moore-Penrose inverse that way. It may or may not give you the standard deviations on the diagonal though.

Comment: Thanks!. BTW, which one should I use, $U\Lambda^{1/2}$ or $\Omega_s$?

Comment: @regress, I added a link to shrinkage estimation. This will all break down when the number of elements is much larger than the num of observations.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation you're using here. What is $N_p$? Why can $X$ be described in terms of $N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you normalize each variable separately, so for each element $i$ you compute its own mean $\mu_i$ and the standard deviation $s_i$ to normalize. This is not a problem with large number of dimensions, as described in this case.

Your suggestion about using the covariance matrix is reasonable too. Take a look at mahalonobis distance, for instance MATLAB's [mahal function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mahal.html), which does exactly what you just described, except for the dimension issue.

The dimension issue is a numerical one, see the shrinkage estimation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices#Shrinkage_estimation). You are estimating NxN matrix whereas your data set is NxT and $T<N$. The problem is that your data set is smaller than the number of parameters you want to estimate, i.e. covariances. This will not cause any problems for linear algebra, matrix inverse will work fine. It's just how reliable is the covariance matrix estimate? MATLAB's mahal function will work on your data with no problem reported in most cases.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I was thinking about normalizing each variable separately as you mentioned. I was not sure which way is more reasonable. I think the second method using the covariance matrix considers correlation between variables, and the first method(normalizing each variable separately) doesn't.

Comment: In your case you can't reliably estimate pair-wise correlation, as I explained in my post. Therefore, in my opinion, you better off not going that route.

Comment: Yes, it's my opinion that when $N*T<<N*N$ the covariance matrix is not reliable, and should not be used. Here N is the number of elements, and T is the number of observations.

Comment: So.. are you meaning that when the dimension of features is larger than the number of samples, the covariance matrix is not reliable? Is it more reasonable to use only the diagonal(variances) of the covariance matrix which is equivalent to normalizing each variable separately?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The variance estimate will be reliable, so I'd use univariate scaling, i.e. each element separately in your case.